# com.android.builder.packaging.DuplicateFileException in android studio

Tags: java, android, google-bigquery

I am not getting how to resolve this? Can anyone suggest me some solutions

My Application Gradle.

```
   apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

    android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.0"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.admin.bigquerytutorials"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
 }

   dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    compile 'com.google.cloud:google-cloud-bigquery:0.26.0-beta'
    }
```

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformResourcesWithMergeJavaResForDebug'.

> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.builder.packaging.DuplicateFileException: Duplicate files copied in APK project.properties
>       File1: C:\Users\Admin.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\com.google.cloud\google-cloud-bigquery\0.26.0-beta\69de62300e43f068fee504fbc055fce5d2e64b94\google-cloud-bigquery-0.26.0-beta.jar
>       File2: C:\Users\Admin.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\com.google.cloud\google-cloud-core\1.8.0\98ede50a9dfdf818204cfc65e494936feb8c5078\google-cloud-core-1.8.0.jar

Comment: use `compile 'com.google.cloud:google-cloud-bigquery:0.28.0-beta'`

Comment: `compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion "26.0.2"`

Comment: Thanks for your reply but that gave me same error with different version

Comment: Have you tried removing => 
compile 'com.google.cloud:google-cloud-bigquery:0.26.0-beta'   ?

Comment: @Md. Didarul islam I cant because i am using bigQuery classes in my code. If i remove it it will show me 'can't resolve error in my code'

Comment: `'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'`

Comment: you should use `compile 'com.google.cloud:google-cloud-bigquery:0.28.0-beta'` instead of  `compile 'com.google.cloud:google-cloud-bigquery:0.26.0-beta'`

Comment: Make sure your local lib having same library or not

Comment: I did all changes suggested by you but that gave me same error with different version

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Your app level gradle. Whatever you get duplicate put it here. I was getting in project.properties. I did that and it worked

```
android{
   ......
   ......
   ......

packagingOptions {
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
    exclude 'META-INF/io.netty.versions.properties'
    exclude 'META-INF/INDEX.LIST'
    exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
    exclude 'project.properties' <<<<<-------This line worked for me
}
}
```